# Android PagerAdapter destroyItem(), caches for a while when using fragments

Tags: android

I'm using Android-support-v4

I have a PagerAdapter that displays a list fragment in each page.

I noticed that when swiping pages, each page displays the fragment of the previous page first (for 1 second) then displays the correct fragment of the given position.

I solved this caching issue by removing the call to

```
super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
```

in the **public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)** method.

I can't find an explanation for this, can anybody explain what happened ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I got it
in the **destroyItem** method, I removed the call to the super `super.destroyItem(container, position, object);`

really don't know an explanation, but I believe cause the parent class removes the views
from the page at the given index, in my case it's supposed to remove FRAGMENTS not VIEWS.